# Rails how to save the requested url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I have two different ways to access the url "localhost:3000/childrens/new".

I have a drop down in childrens/new page and when the user selects an option through the drop down, it shows the different partials using ajax to call the childrens#new method.

1. accessing the childrens new page from url "localhost:3000/parents"
2. accessing the childrens new page from url "localhost:3000/parents1"

After the children have been successfully created, the user should be redirected to the relevant url (either localhost:3000/parents or localhost:3000/parents1)

Comment: Save the url from dropdown as string variable and parse to redirect url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way of how you can achieve this.

One solution would be to store the referrer inside of the session/cookie when the childrens/new is requested: (inside children_controller)

```
def new
  session['children_new_referrer'] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
  #....YOUR CODE....
end
```

And then using that referrer value stored in session/cookie to redirect appropriately:

```
def create
  #.....YOUR CODE....
  if @child.save
    format.html {redirect_to (session['children_new_referrer'] || parents_path)}
  #.....YOUR CODE....
end
```

where @child is the object which I assume you are building with the parameters, and parents_path is being defined through your routes. Feel free to adjust these two based on your needs.

An alternative solution would be to not use sessions, but instead save the referrer uri/path inside of the children/new form page itself. This alternative has the benefit of making the solution session/request scope independent with handling the requirement of storing the referral uri/path within the page scope.

Answer (score 2):

Store the value in session like `session[:last_request]` in parent

After create children redirect it to `session[:last_request] || session[:return_to]` and after that clear the `session[:last_request]`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
def create

redirect_to :back

end
```

redirect_to :back should come after save.

Comment: It redirects to the localhost:3000/childrens/new if i use request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].

Answer (score 0):

Pass the referrer as a parameter in the link. I would much prefer this solution to using the session store.

```
<%= link_to "New child", new_child_path(referrer: @parent.id) %>
```

.. or whatever you want to call it. Then you can inspect `params[:referrer]`. You're not wanting to persist data across a 'session', so why use the session store.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.url
```

in your controller gives the url you are asking for.
So,

```
def create
    if @child.save
        redirect_to request.url
    end
end
```

will do the job perfectly