# Not able to save from data for a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I am new to rails and finishing up the Michael Hartl tutorial and creating some variations on the basic app from the book.  One thing I am trying to do is create a set of model associations that is three deep (user-> colleciotn-> pictures ->).  I am also trying to place my pictures form in the view for showing collections. I tried following the pattern used in the book for the User to collection relationship, but have had several issues.  First, I could not use the Form_with tag (**form_with(model: @picture, local: true)**) and ended up writing out the path (**form_with(url:"/pictures/create", method: "post")**). Also, I used a hidden field tag to pass the collection_id to the "create" method.

My issue now seems to be that it is not saving the @picture data in the Picture Controller. Here is the line I think is suspect:

```
@picture= @collection.pictures.build
```

Here is a summary/my understanding of what I am trying to do.

1. render the Picture form on the Controller show page
2. Post the form date to the picture model, while also passing the
   Controller object ID to the controller so to preserve the picture to controller relationship
3. Call the Controller object using the controller ID that was sent in
   params
4. Save the Picture params to the Picture model with .build and flash a success message

From the logs, I believe the issue is with my use of the .build (highlighted below in code).

I will provide the code below for all of the elements of the app, as well as the log.  I could really use some help figuring out what I am doing wrong.  Let me know if there is anything else I should share.

**Models**

Picture Models

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection

  validates :collection_id, presence: true
  validates :picture_title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30}
end
```

Collection Model

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy


  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :collection_title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pictures, through: :collections 

  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
     return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  def feed
    Collection.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  post   '/pictures/create', to: 'pictures#create'

  resources :users
  resources :collections
  resources :pictures 


  resources :users do
    resources :collection
  end

  resources :collections do
    resources :pictures 
  end

end
```

**Picure Controller**

```
def create

  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])



  @picture= @collection.pictures.build

    if @picture.save!
      flash[:notice] = "Picture was successfully added."
      redirect_to request.referrer 
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Picture could not be saved."
      redirect_to request.referrer 
    end
end


private

  def correct_user
      @collection = current_user.collections.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @collection.nil?
  end

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture_title)
  end

end
```

**Collections Controller**

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :show, :index]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy, :show]

        def show
            @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
            @picture= Picture.new
        end 

        def create
            @collection = current_user.collections.build(collection_params)
                if @collection.save
                    flash[:success] = "Image collection created!"
                    redirect_to root_url
                else
                    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
                    render 'static_pages/home'
                end
        end

        def destroy
            @collection.destroy
            flash[:success] = "Collection deleted"
            redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
        end

    private

        def collection_params
            params.require(:collection).permit(:collection_title)
        end

        def correct_user
            @collection = current_user.collections.find_by(id: params[:id])
            redirect_to root_url if @collection.nil?
        end


end
```

**Picture Form **

```
<%= form_with(url:"/pictures/create", method: "post") do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :picture_title, placeholder: "Picture Title" %>
        </div>
    <%= f.submit "Create Collection", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :collection_id, @collection.id %>
<% end %>
```

**Logs**

```
Started POST "/pictures/create" for 99.150.231.55 at 2020-01-04 19:29:08 +0000
Cannot render console from 99.150.231.55! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by PicturesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"GNDEKiGPVP7EHRtgphGDMIJxbKgnXn2MFSmgTJMIoEo2Owan5THjMIx9N8pKLkS7hmaqJMdwhjqvuOBR/3JaHg==", "picture_title"=>"TEST", "collection_id"=>"10", "commit"=>"Create Collection"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:18:in `current_user'
  Collection Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = ? ORDER BY "collections"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:12:in `create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 2423)



NoMethodError (undefined method `picture_title=' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

**EDIT** 
I implemented Max's code corrections, but now getitng the following error:

```
    Started POST "/collections/10/pictures" for 99.150.231.55 at 2020-01-05 17:57:57 +0000
Cannot render console from 99.150.231.55! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)

NoMethodError (undefined method `make_response!' for PicturesController:Class):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things are off here. First axe this junk:

```
post   '/pictures/create', to: 'pictures#create' # never do this again please.
```

The route here to create a picture is going to be `POST /collections/:collection_id/pictures`. Which RESTfully describes that we are creating a picture that belongs to a collection. You already have that route setup by:

```
resources :collections do
  resources :pictures 
end
```

In rails the action is only ever in the path for `/edit` and `/new`. All the other actions are defined by the HTTP verb.

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_collection, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  # POST /collections/1/pictures
  def create
    @picture = @collection.pictures.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      flash[:notice] = "Picture was successfully added."
      redirect_to @collection
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Picture could not be saved."
      render 'collections/show'
    end
  end

  # ...

  private
  def set_collection
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
  end

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:picture_title)
  end
end
```

Don't do `redirect_to request.referrer` when a record is not valid (or really at all). Many clients do not send the HTTP referer header and it will make for a really bad user experience as any user input and the validation messages are lost. Most of the time you actually know where you should send the user like in your Collections#destroy method which should probably redirect to the index or the users feed. If you really want redirect back reliably [save the location in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040221/rails-how-to-save-the-requested-url).

The form should read:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@collection, @picture]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :picture_title, placeholder: "Picture Title" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Since the collection id is in the path we don't need to do that hacky garbage of using a hidden input to pass it. This also binds the form to the model instance so that the user input is not lost if the input is invalid.

Comment: This is really just scraping the surface through. You should really get rid of the homemade password encryption and use Rails built in `has_secure_password`. Hartl just includes it in the book to teach the basics, and its not something you should be doing. https://blog.codinghorror.com/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels/

Comment: This worked.  Thanks so much Max.  I really appreciated helping me get unstuck.  Seeing what you did also helped me understand some of the concepts better.

Comment: My bad the controller should inherit from ApplicationController. ‘class PictureController < ApplicationController‘

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that part out and it worked once I restarted the server.